# Font-weight issue

Tags: fonts, photoshop, webfonts

I have a "small" question about naming and font-weight. Here's what I understand:

```
900 - Black
800 - Extra bold
700 - Bold
600 - Semi bold
500 - Medium
400 - Normal
300 - Light
200 - Extra light
100 - Thin
```

And it's true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop

w3 seems to be a pretty good reliable source ;) So yeah, thats about correct!

Answer (score 0):

Though this list is pretty spot on, not all fonts will have all of these weights loaded into them though.
That being said, you can't just pick any arbitrary font and give it a weight of, say, 800, and expect it to be extra bold.
If the chosen size isn't available, it will error out and serve up the default 400.